# Want To Return First Response Timestamp As Null If The Case Origin Is Web

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, automation, workflowrule

I'm trying to ensure that two of our fields, which are formula based, return as Null if the Case Origin field (object = Case) is "Web". If it's any other origin source, the First Response (Mins) field and First Response (Days) fields are populated.

The current formula for Response Time (Mins) is:

```
ABS((Second_Outbound_Email__c- CreatedDate)*24*60)
```

The current formula for Response Time (Days) is:

```
ABS((CreatedDate - Second_Outbound_Email__c))
```

I tried to do a Flow, but doesn't seem like Formulas are able to be selected. Any ideas? Currently it looks like there's a trigger when a case is created to where this field is auto-populated.

Comment: Can you not change the formula field to be: `IF (ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Web'),NULL,ABS((Second_Outbound_Email__c- CreatedDate)*24*60))` ?

Comment: Would that return a value if the Origin wasn't web?

Comment: yes - the false path of the IF formula returns your calculated difference of dates

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IF function of the SFDC Formula language](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_if.htm&type=5)

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Web'),
    NULL,
    ABS((Second_Outbound_Email__c- CreatedDate)*24*60)
)
```

and for your second formula field

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Web'),
    NULL,
    ABS((CreatedDate - Second_Outbound_Email__c))
)
```

- First argument is the condition; note use of `ISPICKVAL` on picklists
- Second argument is the IF statement's value when the condition is TRUE
- Third argument is the IF statement's value when the condition is FALSE